# Making Shiny Server (really bigrquery) think R is being run interactively

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, httr

I have a shiny app up on Shiny server, but one of the packages used in the app gets angry if R is not in interactive mode. For the functionality I'm using I don't need interactivity.

I know I can use the --interactive option when launch R from the command line. Is there a way to pass this to shiny server?

Thanks!

Edit - the specific problem seems to be with the bigrquery package. Calling `query_exec` from shiny server returns an error: `interactive() is not TRUE`.

Comment: Can you redefine `interactive` so that it returns `TRUE`.

Comment: hi @jdharrison . I already looked into that. interactive is not simply an option. Interactivity is checked by calling the `interactive()` function in base. It seems you can't redefine functions in base. I could write a local `interactive()` function, but the issue is in a package, so making a local function isn't going to affect the package.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following in global.R would help (taking care to note the disclaimers in `?assignInNamespace` etc.):

```
interactive <- function(){TRUE}
unlockBinding(sym="interactive", env=getNamespace("base"));
assignInNamespace(x="interactive", value=interactive, ns=asNamespace("base"), envir=getNamespace("base"));
assign("interactive", interactive, envir=getNamespace("base"));
lockBinding(sym="interactive", env=getNamespace("base"));
> 
> rm(interactive)
> interactive
function(){TRUE}
> base::interactive
function(){TRUE}
```

Comment: Thanks @jdharrson but unfortunately this does not work. I am not exactly sure why. But I tried the opposite experiment--forcing `interactive` to `FALSE`, and then the package (bigrquery) still ran.

If it makes a difference, the problem seems to be with the httr package, specifically oauth-listener, at least according to this [discussion on github](https://github.com/hadley/bigrquery/issues/28)

Comment: I went a step further and tried to override oauth-listener forcing interactive to FALSE to see if I could break it in a normal R session, but it worked. Maybe something deeper is involved.